# from_user_id cannot be null?

Tags: mysql

i am trying to make my sql insert function more secure, at the moment it says insert $_SESSION['user_id'] as from_user_id, but i have also noticed that a user is able to hack this and set from_user_id to 0 or NULL and i want to add a condition that basically says insert $session['user_id'] into from_user_id but do not allow from_user_id to be NULL else do not insert and give an error:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_wallposts (id, from_user_id, to_user_id, content) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$profile_id."', '".$content."');";
    mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

Comment: I presume `id` is an auto-incrementing number and doesn't need to be included in your insert statement. In addition, if you want it to be secure, you might want to brush up on PHP PDO.

Comment: id is an auto increment column

Comment: This logic should be handled on the application side.

Answer (score 0):

you can also set your database field as NOT NULL.